# Cannot expose port to access webserver from localhost in browser [docker]

Tags: tomcat, docker, jenkins

I just started learning docker and got stuck here. So first I tried to run jenkins image and map a port so I can access it from my browser, but I didn't succeed. When I open localhost from browser at the specified port I get nothing. The same was with tomcat.

I run it like this: `docker run -it --rm -p 8888:8080 tomcat` and I get output in cmd prompt like everything is setup like it should, but nothing appears in browser. And in `docker ps` I can see that tomcat container is running on port 8888 like it should.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a couple of steps you could follow to trace the issue:

**Check if the service is running correctly inside the container**
you can enter the container using:

```
docker exec -it [container id] bash [or ash depends on your image]
```

and then check if the container is running your desired service correctly running telnet could be useful here.

Or you could check the container logs. simply run on host:

```
docker logs [container id]
```

**check if docker is correctly binding your ports**

run on host :

```
sudo netstat -nlp | grep :8888
```

this should list that the **dockerd** 'docker daemon' is using the port

**And if all of that went well then you should check your firewall rules as it could be preventing any connection on these ports**

**p.s.** the `--rm` option means that [Docker](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#clean-up-rm) will automatically clean up the container and remove the file system when the container exits. So there is no persistence whatsoever.

Hope this was useful.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it helped definitely, but the problem was that I was checking the wrong IP.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was checking the wrong IP. On localhost I wasn't able to access anything running in docker containers, but when I tried the address that is provided in cmd prompt every time when docker is started I got what I want.